# form_for routing error with scope :module nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This may not make sense but I'm trying  to learn harder stuff and progress, it seems like I'm missing the ID for address but can't seem to find a solution.

I included the url in form_for because when I remove it, the app breaks. But seems like I predefined the url than edit breaks.

```
 <%= form_for([@address.user, @address], :url => user_addresses_path) do |f| %>
```

Error Readout:
No route matches [PATCH] "/users/1/addresses"

When I remove :url=>
undefined method `user_client_address_path'

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    # Security Devise Setup
    devise_for :admins
    devise_for :users

    # Main Pages
    root 'website/page#index'

    # Client Sections
    resources :users do
        scope module: "client" do
            root :to => 'dashboard#index'
            resources :addresses
        end
    end

    namespace :admin do
        root :to => 'panel#index'
    end

end
```

rake routes partial output (let me know if more is needed)

```
user_addresses      GET    /users/:user_id/addresses(.:format)          client/addresses#index
                    POST   /users/:user_id/addresses(.:format)          client/addresses#create
new_user_address    GET    /users/:user_id/addresses/new(.:format)      client/addresses#new
edit_user_address   GET    /users/:user_id/addresses/:id/edit(.:format) client/addresses#edit
user_address        GET    /users/:user_id/addresses/:id(.:format)      client/addresses#show
                    PATCH  /users/:user_id/addresses/:id(.:format)      client/addresses#update
                    PUT    /users/:user_id/addresses/:id(.:format)      client/addresses#update
                    DELETE /users/:user_id/addresses/:id(.:format)      client/addresses#destroy
```

Comment: What is the output of `rake routes`? For some reason your form is submitting using PATCH instead of POST. Are you trying to submit via AJAX?

Comment: Are you submitting your form via AJAX? or does it have a submit button you click?

Comment: Interesting. It has two entries. PATCH/PUT. I have an admin template that could be causing the problem. Probably some sort of JavaScript or AJAX somewhere.

Comment: I'll check into that. The only thing assigned to form buttons is Twitter Bootstrap class.

Comment: Yeah but the PATCH/PUT are for the single address edit. You are using `user_addresses_path` which only have GET and POST

Comment: Try adding `method: :post` to the `form_for` hash right after url. Like `<%= form_for([@address.user, @address], url: user_addresses_path, method: :post) do |f| %>`

Comment: That worked. If you don't mind just throwing that line in an answer I can give you credit.

Comment: Thanks Again. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AJAX to submit the form, try adding `method: 'POST'` to it.

If you are submitting the form normally, try adding `method: :post` to the `form_for` hash.

It should end up something like:

`<%= form_for([@address.user, @address], url: user_addresses_path, method: :post) do |f| %>`